Use Office 365 to edit files in my app and save them back to my server
My application is an online document management system. Currently, I only use Office to implement online editing of Word. I hope to use Microsoft Office 365 instead of OnlyOffice. Is there a feasible way to use 365 for online editing in my web application?
The implementation is similar to that the file is stored in my server, and the file is transferred to Office 365 only when it needs to be edited or previewed online. After the editing in Office 365 is completed, the changes to the file can be returned to my server.
current implementation

I tried looking up Microsoft's official documentation, but couldn't find a feasible implementation.
